# Firebase/Firestore test project has different behaviour in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, firefox, google-cloud-firestore

In order to testing `Firebase` and `Firestore` I write this simple file but I don't understand why it works differently using `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

- in `Chrome` it seems that data is stored locally in `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\IndexedDB` and never send to Firestore backend
- in `Firefox` the web project console is updated immediatly when I click the button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

 <script>

  var config = {
   apiKey: "myApiKey",
   authDomain: "myAppName.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://myAppName.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "myAppName",
   storageBucket: "myAppName.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "1234567890"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var db = firebase.firestore();

  function addRandomItem() {

   db.collection("items").doc("random_item_" + new Date().getTime()).set({
    description: "random item description",
    notes: "random item notes"
   })
    .then(function () {
     window.alert("Document successfully written.");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     window.alert("Error adding document: " + error);
    });
  }

 </script>

</head>

<body>
 <button onclick="addRandomItem()">add random item</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a `CORS` (cross-origin resource sharing) problem: testing my file in Chrome using a web server and not via file system solve the problem.